# How to Convert Date format '01-10-2020' (dd-mm-yyyy) to '2020-10-01' (yyyy-mm-dd)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have date column, having format '01-10-2020' (dd-mm-yyyy).

I want to covert it into SQL date format i.e. '2020-10-01' (yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: If you actually have a date column, of datatype date, then it has no format. You only format it in your presentation layer when you try and display it. And if you have stored your dates as `varchar` I suggest changing them to `date` asap. And then if you still need to format them in SQL, please do some research and you will find that SQL Server has a `convert` function and a `format` function. And if you have a `varchar` and need to format it, convert it to a date then format as normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solition:

MYSQL

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01-10-2020','%Y-%m-%d');
```

MSSQL

```
SELECT FORMAT (TRY_CAST('01-01-2000' as date), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as date
```